# Error while importing csv file using MSSQL Import extension in Azure Data Studio on Pop!_OS

Tags: docker, sql-server, import, pop-os, azure-data-studio

I have an `Intel Aspire 5738` laptop which has `Intel Core 2 Duo processor T6400 (2.00 GHz, 800 MHz FSB)` on which i have installed the latest version of `POP!_OS`. The CPU does not support virtualization. However, i was finally able to install Docker and run Microsoft SQL-Server. As there was no Microsoft SSMS GUI available for linux, i installed the latest light-weight `Azure Data Studio` GUI and it works well.

The problem i am facing is when i installed `Microsoft CSV Import` extension in Azure Data Studio and tried to import a CSV as a table into my database. The Import wizard shoots different errors on the 2nd step:

```
- Error: Connection got disposed.
- Language client is not ready yet
- Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

and when i check the extension page, i see this error in runtime status:

[image: cannot read property "map" of undefined]

Does anyone know why this is happening and what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: Why is this extension marked as "Preview"? Normally this means experimental.

Comment: don't know. i installed it directly from the extensions section in azure data studio.

Comment: Try perhaps to find an alternative.

Comment: I wish i knew if there is an alternative. I did search but could not locate one...nor an earlier version...